# Why is .append not adding string to the list?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a menu (only 25% complete as of now) and whenever I input a number for example 3, the list `z` outputs a value of `z = ['']`

```
print("Welcome to Kushagra's Pizzeria!")
z = []
a = ""
print('''
Please select a size-
                      1.Small
                      2.Medium
                      3.Large
''')
y = input("-->")
if y == 1:
    a = "Small"
elif y == 2:
    a = "Medium"
elif y == 3:
    a = "Large"
z.append(a)
print(z)
```

Comment: ```input``` returns a string so you need to either change ```y == "1"``` or ```y = int(input())```

Answer (score 1):

You either convert the input to `int` or look for the string value

```
y == "1"
```

or

```
int(input("-->"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string. you need to convert it to an integer by calling the [`int`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/int) method

```
y = int(input("-->"))
```